# Changing view inside TabHost (one activity, multiple views)

Tags: android, view, tabs, android-tabhost

right now I'm using in my application tabhost with single activity and separate views.

Tab Activity:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);        
    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec(TAB_HOTELS);
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Hotels");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec = tabs.newTabSpec(TAB_LAST_MINUTE);
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Last Minute");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ListView android:id="@+id/listaLocalita"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingTop="60px">
                <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100px" android:text="This is tab 2"
                    android:id="@+id/txt2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And things are working quite well as long as i'm using one level depth. Unfortunately now I need to make one of the tab to work like following:

Tab loading ListView with the list of cities, User clicks on city name, tab's content is replaced with the list of the Hotels, user choose a hotel and always in the the same tab, hotel's info is loaded.

How can i achieve this scenario? LayoutInflater?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking at doing something similar.

Comment: Just See [this Example](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html). Hope it will Help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use intent to set Activity as your tab content, and this activity can call other activities, either listView or any other.

```
/** tid1 is firstTabSpec Id. Its used to access outside. */
        TabSpec MainTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        TabSpec SearchTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
        TabSpec MessageTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag3");
        TabSpec ServicesTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag4");
        TabSpec SettingsTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag5");

        MainTab.setIndicator("Main", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.anchor_36));
        MainTab.setContent(new Intent(this, MainView.class));

    SearchTab.setIndicator("Search", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_36));
    SearchTab.setContent(new Intent(this, SearchView.class));

    MessageTab.setIndicator("Messages", res
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.dialog_36));
    MessageTab.setContent(new Intent(this, MessagesView.class));

    ServicesTab.setIndicator("Services", res
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.cloud_36));
    ServicesTab.setContent(new Intent(this, ServicesView.class));

    SettingsTab.setIndicator("Settings", res
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.settings_36));
    SettingsTab.setContent(new Intent(this, SettingsView.class));

    /** Add tabSpec to the TabHost to display. */
    tabHost.addTab(MainTab);
    tabHost.addTab(SearchTab);
    tabHost.addTab(MessageTab);
    tabHost.addTab(ServicesTab);
    tabHost.addTab(SettingsTab);
```

Now in the loaded activity you can use the code like

```
StartActivity(new intent(currentActivity.this, newActivity.class));
```

this will work for you.

Comment: shure, but this will launch `newActivity` not inside the Tab, but in a single Window...